# Fit Doubly Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods, normal-distribution, variance

I would like to estimate the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of a doubly truncated normal distribution. Following things are given: the interval $[a,b]$, the mean and the variance of the truncated data. I am not sure how to approach this issue. Would be really helpful if someone could give me a hint.

More details:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: What would you do if the data came from an untruncated normal distribution?

Comment: Your Wikipedia link gives the mean and variance of the truncated distribution in terms of $\mu,\sigma^2,\alpha,\beta$, so the answer will probably be that you can find $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ from the others using numerical methods